# Remover caracteres do meio de uma String

Tags: java, string, concatenação-de-string

Escreva um programa que, começando numa palavra definida por si, imprima no ecrã as palavras resultantes de ir retirando, um a um, os caracteres do meio da palavra anterior, até chegar a uma palavra com um só caractere. Se o número de caracteres da palavra for par, será retirado o primeiro dos dois caracteres do meio.

Exemplo: se a palavra for `rapsodia`, o programa deverá imprimir as palavras:

> rapsodia, rapodia, rapdia, radia, raia, ria, ra e a.

Comecei por fazer o seguinte:

```
public class Exercicios {

    //5
    static String semLetraMeio(String s) {

        int sLength = s.length();
        while(sLength > 1) {

            int midIndex = sLength / 2;
            s = s.substring(0, midIndex).concat(s.substring(midIndex + 1, sLength));
            System.out.println(s);

        }

        return s;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        semLetraMeio("zero");

    }

}
```

Comment: Na minha opinião seria melhor fazer uma chamada recursiva e criar menos variáveis, como aqui:

```java
static String semLetraMeio(String s) {
    if (s != null) {
        if (s.length() == 0)
            return s;
 System.out.println(s);
 return semLetraMeio(new StringBuilder(s).deleteCharAt(s.length() % 2 == 0 ? s.length() / 2 - 1 : s.length() / 2).toString());
 }
 return s;
    }
```

Comment: @yurishimoki Não vejo porque recursão é melhor pra esse caso. Vc pode até ter criado menos variáveis, mas vai ocupar mais espaço no stack com esse monte de chamadas recursivas (talvez seja até pior que "evitar variáveis") - e fazer tudo em uma linha somente para evitar variáveis nem sempre torna o código "melhor". Variáveis não são um mal a ser evitado, vc usa quando fizer sentido e só é ruim criar variáveis que não servem para nada ou deixam o código menos claro. E eu acho que faz sentido criar uma para o índice a ser removido, por exemplo, já que é o ponto central do algoritmo :-)

Comment: Neste caso:
`static String semLetraMeio(String s) {
    if (s != null) {
      if (s.length() == 0)
        return s;
      while (s.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println(s);
        s = new StringBuilder(s)
        .deleteCharAt(s.length() % 2 == 0 ? s.length() / 2 - 1 : s.length() / 2)
        .toString());
      }
    return s;
    }
  return s;
}`

Comment: Só que como Strings são imutáveis, isso seria melhor: `static String semLetraMeio(String s) {
    if (s != null) {
      if (s.length() == 0)
        return s;
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
      while (sb.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println(sb);
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() % 2 == 0 ? sb.length() / 2 - 1 : sb.length() / 2);
      }
    return sb.toString();
    }
  return s;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você calcula o tamanho da `String` somente no começo, antes do `while`. Mas depois da primeira iteração, a `String` terá um caractere a menos, e aí você vai tentar pegar uma `substring` até `sLength`, que agora é maior do que o tamanho da `String` (afinal, você retirou um caractere), e isso causará um [`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). E mesmo que esse erro não ocorresse, o programa entraria em *loop* infinito, afinal `sLength` nunca é atualizado no `while`.

Então uma solução seria atualizar o tamanho da `String` a cada iteração. Outro detalhe é que quando o tamanho da `String` é par, você está pegando o segundo caractere do meio, então tem que ser feito um ajuste para este caso:

```
static void semLetraMeio(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    int sLength = s.length();
    while (sLength > 1) {
        int midIndex = sLength / 2;
        if (sLength % 2 == 0) { // ajuste para quando o tamanho é par
            midIndex--;
        }
        s = s.substring(0, midIndex).concat(s.substring(midIndex + 1, sLength));
        System.out.println(s);
        sLength = s.length();
    }
}
```

Outro detalhe é que eu mudei o retorno do método para `void`, pois não parece fazer sentido ele retornar alguma coisa (ele vai retornar a última `substring` encontrada). Bom, se achar que faz sentido, é só colocar de volta o `return` e o retorno do método para `String`.

Também coloquei um `println` no início para imprimir a `String` original. Chamando `semLetraMeio("rapsodia")`, a saída é:

```
rapsodia
rapodia
rapdia
radia
raia
ria
ra
a
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), que possui o método [`deleteCharAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt%28int%29), que serve justamente para apagar um caractere em determinada posição:

```
static void semLetraMeio(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    while (sb.length() > 0) {
        int midIndex = sb.length() / 2;
        if (sb.length() % 2 == 0) {
            midIndex--;
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(midIndex);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Se quiser que o método retorne uma `String`, como o seu código original faz, mude para:

```
static String semLetraMeio(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    while (sb.length() > 0) {
        int midIndex = sb.length() / 2;
        if (sb.length() % 2 == 0) {
            midIndex--;
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(midIndex);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua lógica está certa, apenas esqueceu de alguns detalhes:

```
public class Main {
   // ja que a função apenas printa as Strings não há necessidade de retornos
   static void semLetraMeio(String s) {
        int sLength = s.length();
        while(sLength > 1) {
          int midIndex = (sLength - 1) / 2; // vc deve diminuir 1 no length para pegar o primeiro char do meio caso o numero seja par
          s = s.substring(0, midIndex).concat(s.substring(midIndex + 1));
          sLength = s.length(); // vc tbm esqueceu de definir o novo tamanho da string, causando um loop infinto
          System.out.println(s);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      semLetraMeio("rapsodia");
    }
}
```